# Net raid FS with FUSE, gcc -hello.c -o a.out, a.out is not executable

Tags: c, gcc, permissions, executable, system-calls

I'm writing net raid FS with FUSE on ubuntu. Here are syscalls I've implemented: `create` `open` `read` `write` `release` `unlink` `mkdir` `opendir` `readdir` `releasedir` `rmdir` `getattr` and `rename`.

Everything works fine, but here is such case: I wrote "hello world" in c and tried typing this: `gcc hello.c -o a.out`. `a.out` is fine, but it's just a file, not executable (When I set manually 0777 permissions it executes fine on `./a.out`).

When permissions must be set, and how? And when compiling, how to know which files should be set exe permissions? Based on what?

Comment: It shoud be a file, not a directory.

Comment: The compiler automatically sets execute permissions when it's creating the executable file. It probably does it with the third argument to `open()`, so I suspect you're not implementing that properly.

Comment: @Barmar sorry my mistake. I meant file :X

Comment: The compiler (actually the linker) probably does `open(outputfile, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0555)` so that the file should get read and execute permissions. Make sure you implement this correctly.

Comment: @Barmar I printed creation permissions and it appears to be 33204 `printf("permissions: %s %d\n", path, mode);`; regular file with 204 permission right? And why is that way?

Comment: You should print permissions in octal so it's understandable.

Comment: Actually, it probably uses `0555`, and relies on `umask` to remove the group and world write permissions.

Comment: `33204` is `0100664`

Comment: 100664 in octal mode; But still why exe permissions are not set? (I printed this on the first line of `create` syscall)

Comment: Maybe it creates it without execute permissions, then calls `chmod()` when it's done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176677/discussion-between-data-chanturia-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lacked `chmod` syscall implementation. `chmod` makes it work all right. Thanks @Barmar for help!